# Mint 19.x and Python MKL: segmentation fault on import numpy

Tags: linux, linux-mint, python3

After a recent update of computers running Mint 19.x (19.1, 19.2 and 19.3), I noticed that I cannot import specific libraries such as `numpy` or `scipy` in my Intel Python environment. I get the following error:

```
login@my_pc:~$ python
Python 3.7.7 (default, Sep 11 2020, 20:43:12) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Intel Corporation on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Intel(R) Distribution for Python is brought to you by Intel Corporation.
Please check out: https://software.intel.com/en-us/python-distribution
>>> import numpy
double free or corruption (!prev)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am pretty sure this is related to a recent `apt-get update` / `apt-get upgrade` that I ran on these systems since other PCs with Mint 18.x and 20.x do not have this issue. I tried to investigate the origin of this issue running `python -v`, this gave me:

```
>>> import numpy
...
import 'textwrap' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbfbeb0d790>
double free or corruption (!prev)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

For every problematic library import, the issue seems related to the import of `textwrap` (though `import textwrap` in python does work fine) ... Does anyone know if there is a fix for this ?

**update**: after checking the log of my last update, I believe the source of this error is the transition from `gcc 7.4` to `gcc 7.5`. I am trying to go back to `gcc 7.4`...

Comment: How did you install numpy?

Comment: @ajgringo619, I installed Intel Python (version 2020.4.912) that includes a pre-compiled version of numpy and scipy, My "regular" numpy with Python 3 is working well. The issue only occurs for my Intel Python environment.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may encounter this problem, it does seem that the latest update of libc libraries on Mint 19.x lead to a broken install for Python MKL. I had to update my PCs to Mint 20 to solve the issue.